# List Categories in Custom Order

Tags: categories

I'm using this code:

```
<?php wp_list_categories('include=19,20,21,22,23,24&orderby=date&title_li=<h4>' . __('Prices') . '</h2>' ); ?>
```

But it's not displaying categories in the order by date, and I'd like to custom order the list anyway.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you consider the "order by date" for a category?

Comment: Order by the date I created the categories.

Comment: WordPress **don't** save information about the date a category is created. Normally category ID should be in order of creation, but there is nothing that assure that.